# Newton Lebnitz differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$F(x)$ is Integral of $\dfrac{1}{1+|t-x|}$ wrt $t$ from $0$ to $1$.

I need to find $F'(1/2)$.

If I simply break the limits and from $0$ to $x$ and $x$ to $1$ and open the modulus, I'm getting zero for any value of $x$ belonging between $0$ to $1$, answer given is $1/2$.